# Comcast Xfinity XB7 Gateway w/ wireless printer

Tags: printer, home-networking, wireless-access-point

I just upgraded from a Comcast/Xfinity XB6 to an XB7 and since then I found that my staticly assigned IP wireless printer is no longer working. I think there's a problem with routing, masking, firewall, etc. The printer is an old HP Deskjet 3050 aka J610. I'm trying to print from multiple devices. I'm trying everything but any suggestions would be appreciated.

I've verified connections, dhcp and IPs of all devices. There are management interfaces from xfinity.comcast.net (which they seem to prefer I use) and 10.0.0.1 which look almost identical to the xb6 interfaces I'm used to. I'll look for that option you recommend. Ping works fine from pc to printer.

Comment: Firewall and routing only come to play if the traffic is passing the internet port. I'm not even sure what you're referring to with "masking" in this context. Start with the basics: is your PC connected to Wi-Fi? What's the IP address? What are the IPs of the router and the printer? Check the XB7 mgmt interface - does it allow Wi-Fi clients to communicate with each other? Can you ping the printer's IP from the PC? If you configure the printer for DHCP and restart it, does it receive an IP, and can you ping it from the PC? Please edit your question to update instead of answering in a comment.

Comment: A workaround that seems to work is to use a different access point connected via MOCA. I'd still like to connect it directly.

Comment: Though technically correct, firewall and routing come into play passing traffic to the WAN port there are other ways to limit local traffic for security purposes. I believe some devices have security features that limit connection between devices on a local network. This is the masking I'm talking about. I just don't know if it's happening with this device. I think HP uses it's own protocol, perhaps using a broadcast method not supported by the XB7, to discover printers. This may be getting blocked when setting up devices.

Answer (score 0):

Though not a satisfying answer I found something that works. I didn't spend the time to track down exactly what isn't working. A packet analysis would be best. For now I've simply stopped using the AP in the XB7. I have another AP connected via MOCA which I connect the printer to. It still gets the same IP via DHCP from the XB7. I can now print from multiple devices.